# External SD card no longer able to be read on CM11

Tags: cyanogenmod, external-sd, motorola-droid-razr, file-permissions

I successfully installed CM11-M2 snapshot on my Razr Maxx (xt912, spyder). I was able to use my camera successfully on the device after install. However, now a few weeks in, I am experiencing a few issues related to my external SD card.

- My camera no longer works with an error *"Insert an SD card before using the camera"*
- When attempting to download a file through the browser I get an error stating that an "SD card is required" to download the file
- I use the app EBookDroid, which allows opening files from the filesystem, while I have an entry for `sdcard1` (my external SD card), I cannot view any files inside of it
- With root permissions on my File Manager, I can navigate through and view files in my external SD card, but cannot open them in any other applications

After a little investigating, I see the path `/mnt/media_rw/` which contains two mounted partitions of `sdcard0` and `sdcard1`. These paths belong to the user and group named `media_rw`. My best guess is that this issue is related to these permissions. Here is output of `ls -la` on `/mnt/media_rw`

```
drwx------ media_rw media_rw             2014-03-06 12:47 sdcard0
drwxrwx--- media_rw media_rw             1969-12-31 19:00 sdcard1
```

Is there an `fstab` file I can verify (I dont see one in `/etc/fstab`). Or am I barking up the wrong tree with `media_rw`. Can anyone assist?

Comment: I'm with the same problem. Did you tryied sdfix? And what about this: http://winaero.com/blog/unlock-external-sd-card-writing-for-all-apps-in-android-4-4-kitkat/?

Comment: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/64770/how-can-i-mount-an-ext4-formatted-sd-card-with-correct-permissions-with-root

http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/11301/sd-card-formatted-to-ext4-and-permissions

Similar issues, currently unfixed.

Comment: That a nightly build??

Answer (score 1):

How old is your SD card? Does it work under stock? If it doesn't work under either, I wonder if the SD card is going bad? How long have you had it and do you do a lot of writing to it? If so, then the card might be going bad as SD cards have a limited lifespan. The more you write to it, the shorted the lifespan.

Do you have another SD card you could try? I would also do a chkdsk on it to see if any bad sectors are found. If so, time to ditch it and get a new card.